# Render page then extract source code within VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to download a webpage to scrape data from but doesn't contain the data I need until it's been rendered and run all the Javascript, I'm using the following code to download the page:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.DownloadFile(url, MainForm.mainDir & "\RP\" & fName)
```

Is there a way to render the page first and then extract the source code and save it?
I know it can be done using 'Inspect Element' in Chrome, but I need to do it within VB.NET.

Comment: You can make use of a `WebBrowserControl`. Navigate to the site, maybe wait some time, then use `WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml` to extract the final htm.

Comment: If you don't want the page showing on the form, you can do `WebBrowser1.Visible = False`.

Comment: Cheers, this works.

Comment: you're welcome...